# SparkStreaming for multiple data sources

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We would like to design/develop a DataConnector service using SparkStreaming. 
The data connector service will allow the user to specify a source and destination database, and 
the connection parameters for the same. Therefore, dynamic data connection requests need to be handled by the system. We would like to have one streaming job that can handle all connection requests made to the Data Connector service. 
We propose to handle this in the following manner: 
All connection requests made to the DataConnector service, will be updated in our "meta-store" database. 
We will have a custom receiver which fetches all active connection requests from the meta-store and use the DStream results (database names, connection strings, etc) of the receiver, to fetch data from multiple databases and process the same.

Any problems with this approach?

Comment: Please make your question more specific. What's the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: *Too broad*: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.